# How to convert long to Date in Controller Spring java

Tags: java, spring

I try convert Long to date in Rest API spring java as blow :

```
@RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")Date startDate
```

this is my URL .../schedule?startDate=1496011479000
and i get error :
`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: \"1496011479000\" is malformed at \"9000\""`

what is wrong ?

Comment: you can change type of startDate to long, and remove other annotations. and in method, you can convert that startDate to Date using `Date d = new Date(startDate).`

Comment: @SachinGupta : it's resolve problem so inconvenient.